# NoSuchMethodException thrown by HiltWorker with additional parameters

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt, android-workmanager

I get the following exception for 2 of my CoroutineWorkers with additional parameters injected by Hilt. This does not happen for workers without additional parameters and only happens when I install the app via APK by my fastlane build. Android Studio builds work perfectly. But my build pipeline uses the same settings as Android Studio builds. By work, I mean that the workers get enqueued and do not throw the following exception...

```
Could not instantiate com.example.android.ActivitySyncWorker
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: 
       com.example.android.ActivitySyncWorker.<init> [class android.content.Context, class androidx.work.WorkerParameters]
       at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3325)
       at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:3063)
       at androidx.work.WorkerFactory.createWorkerWithDefaultFallback(WorkerFactory.java:94)
       at androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper.runWorker(WorkerWrapper.java:243)
       at androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper.run(WorkerWrapper.java:144)
       at androidx.work.impl.utils.SerialExecutorImpl$Task.run(SerialExecutorImpl.java:96)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
```

The internal variable of Hilt `mWorkerFactories` is empty. My worker cannot be found then. But with Android Studio builds it's not empty.
Before I continue. What makes this question different from other similar ones is, that I have a multi-module project. Maybe I am missing something because of it.

This is the Worker inside the app module `:core-ble`

```kotlin
@HiltWorker
class ActivitySyncWorker @AssistedInject constructor(
    @Assisted context: Context,
    @Assisted params: WorkerParameters,
    val bleServiceModule: BleServiceModule,
    private val connectionPool: BleConnectionPool,
) : CoroutineWorker(context, params) {
    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
        return coroutineScope {
            try {
                // ...

                Result.success()
            } catch (exception: Exception) {
                SLog.e("[BLE_SYNC] worker error: $exception")
                if (runAttemptCount < 2) {
                    Result.retry()
                } else {
                    Result.failure()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private const val ACTIVITY_SYNC_WORKER_TAG = "activity_sync"

        fun enqueue(context: Context, workManager: WorkManager, workerParams: Data = Data.EMPTY) {
            val workRequest = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<ActivitySyncWorker>(30, TimeUnit.MINUTES).apply {
                addTag(ACTIVITY_SYNC_WORKER_TAG)
                setConstraints(
                    Constraints.Builder()
                        .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
                        .build()
                )
                setInputData(
                    Data.Builder()
                        .putAll(workerParams)
                        .build()
                )
            }.build()

            workManager.enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(
                /* uniqueWorkName = */ ACTIVITY_SYNC_WORKER_TAG,
                /* existingPeriodicWorkPolicy = */ ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.CANCEL_AND_REENQUEUE,
                /* periodicWork = */ workRequest
            )
        }

        fun stop(context: Context) {
            WorkManager.getInstance(context).cancelAllWorkByTag(ACTIVITY_SYNC_WORKER_TAG)
        }
    }
}
```

This worker gets enqueued always, but has no additional injected parameters. Because of reflection, it can be found.

```kotlin
@HiltWorker
class RemoteConfigSyncWorker @AssistedInject constructor(
    @Assisted context: Context,
    @Assisted params: WorkerParameters,
) : CoroutineWorker(context, params) {
    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
        return coroutineScope {
            try {
                // ...

                Result.success()
            } catch (exception: Exception) {
                if (runAttemptCount < 2) {
                    Result.retry()
                } else {
                    Result.failure()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private const val REMOTE_CONFIG_SYNC_WORKER_TAG = "remote_config_sync"

        fun enqueue(workManager: WorkManager, workerParams: Data = Data.EMPTY) {
            val workRequest = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<RemoteConfigSyncWorker>(30, TimeUnit.MINUTES).apply {
                addTag(REMOTE_CONFIG_SYNC_WORKER_TAG)
                setConstraints(
                    Constraints.Builder()
                        .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
                        .build()
                )
                setInputData(
                    Data.Builder()
                        .putAll(workerParams)
                        .build()
                )
            }.build()

            workManager.enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(
                /* uniqueWorkName = */ REMOTE_CONFIG_SYNC_WORKER_TAG,
                /* existingPeriodicWorkPolicy = */ ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.CANCEL_AND_REENQUEUE,
                /* periodicWork = */ workRequest
            )
        }

        fun stop(context: Context) {
            WorkManager.getInstance(context).cancelAllWorkByTag(REMOTE_CONFIG_SYNC_WORKER_TAG)
        }
    }
}
```

As you see in my Manifest, I removed the default Initializer and added my own...

```xml
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
            android:exported="false"
            tools:node="merge">
            <meta-data
                android:name="androidx.work.WorkManagerInitializer"
                android:value="androidx.startup"
                tools:node="remove" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.example.android.WorkManagerModule"
                android:value="androidx.startup" />
        </provider>
```

This is the new Initializer...

```kotlin
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object WorkManagerModule : Initializer<WorkManager> {

    private var isInitialized = false

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    override fun create(@ApplicationContext context: Context): WorkManager {
        if (!isInitialized) { // just in case this gets called twice
            val entryPoint = EntryPointAccessors.fromApplication(
                context,
                HiltWorkerFactoryEntryPoint::class.java
            )

            val configuration = Configuration.Builder()
                .setWorkerFactory(entryPoint.workerFactory())
                .setMinimumLoggingLevel(Log.VERBOSE)
                .build()

            WorkManager.initialize(context, configuration)

            isInitialized = true
        }

        return WorkManager.getInstance(context)
    }

    override fun dependencies(): MutableList<Class<out Initializer<*>>> {
        return mutableListOf()
    }

    @EntryPoint
    @InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
    interface HiltWorkerFactoryEntryPoint {
        fun workerFactory(): HiltWorkerFactory
    }
}
```

I do this in onCreate of my MultiDexApplication which is located in `:app`

```kotlin
AppInitializer.getInstance(this).initializeComponent(WorkManagerModule::class.java)
```

My imports... (in both `:core-ble` and `:app`.

```kotlin
 implementation(libs.hilt)
 implementation(libs.hilt.work)
 implementation(libs.hilt.plugin)
 kapt(libs.hilt.compiler)
 kapt(libs.hilt.androidx.compiler)
 implementation(libs.work.runtime.ktx)
 implementation(libs.startup)
```

```ini
hilt = "2.44.2"
hiltAndroidX = "1.1.0"
hiltCompose = "1.0.0"
hiltWork = "1.0.0"
work = "2.9.0"
hiltKapt = "2.35"

hilt-plugin = { group = "com.google.dagger", name = "hilt-android-gradle-plugin", version.ref = "hilt" }
hilt-kapt = { group = "com.google.dagger", name = "hilt-android-compiler", version.ref = "hiltKapt" }
hilt-compiler = { group = "com.google.dagger", name = "hilt-android-compiler", version.ref = "hilt" }
hilt-androidx-compiler = { group = "androidx.hilt", name = "hilt-compiler", version.ref = "hiltAndroidX" }
hilt-work = { group = "androidx.hilt", name = "hilt-work", version.ref = "hiltWork" }
startup = { group = "androidx.startup", name = "startup-runtime", version.ref = "startup" }
hilt = { group = "com.google.dagger", name = "hilt-android", version.ref = "hilt" }
work-runtime = { group = "androidx.work", name = "work-runtime", version.ref = "work" }
work-runtime-ktx = { group = "androidx.work", name = "work-runtime-ktx", version.ref = "work" }
```

I also tried adding these ProGuard rules, but why should it work with Android Studio builds but not with APK builds.

```
-keepclassmembers class * extends androidx.work.Worker {
    public <init>(android.content.Context,androidx.work.WorkerParameters);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends androidx.work.CoroutineWorker {
    public <init>(android.content.Context,androidx.work.WorkerParameters);
}
```

This is my hilt module for one of the parameters of the WorkManagers. Same for the parameters inside `provideBleServiceModule`

```kotlin
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object BleServiceModuleModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideBleServiceModule(
        @ApplicationContext context: Context,
        sharedPrefHelper: CommonsSharedPrefHelper,
        bluetoothAdapterStateModule: BluetoothAdapterStateModule,
        userDbService: UserDbService,
        bleEvents: BleEvents,
    ): BleServiceModule = BleServiceModule(
        context,
        sharedPrefHelper,
        bluetoothAdapterStateModule,
        userDbService,
        bleEvents,
    )
}
```

Comment: Do you minify the builds with Fastlane? And why do you manually call initializeComponent on the `WorkManagerModule` and also add it to the manifest?

Comment: @tynn I do not minify it... `debug {
            isDebuggable = true
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.getByName("debug")
            proguardFiles("proguard-android.txt")
            isTestCoverageEnabled = false
        }`
You mean that I call initializeComponent in onCreate of my Application? Honestly, I tried everything at this point and just added everything what I could find. Do think this is a problem? What should I remove?

Comment: I don't think calling it manually is necessary. But right now I'm wondering why it's an `Initializer<WorkManager>` and an `object` as well. Also I'm wondering if you use the `com.google.dagger.hilt.android` gradle plugin? Have you followed the guide from https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-jetpack#workmanager?

Comment: It's an object because I originally got it from this blog post https://proandroiddev.com/customize-workmanager-with-appstartup-hilt-97c16d103052 I tried it as a class and it does not work either. I applied the dagger gradle plugin too all build.gradles where I use WorkManagers. `plugins { id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") }`

Comment: Have you tried the approach with the `Configuration.Provider`? With it you wouldn't need to create the `WorkManagerModule` or to disable `WorkManagerInitializer`. The issue seems to be that the provider is not registered in the `HiltWorkerFactory` or the `HiltWorkerFactory` is not used at all.

Comment: I tried it before and just tried it again but it still doesn't work on Fastlane builds. I don't get it why this happens. Fastlane executes the exact same gradle task.

Comment: Since this is a runtime issue, would it be possible for you to debug this part and see if you're using the `HiltWorkerFactory` and which providers are defined in there?

Comment: I did some debugging and it goes into the HiltWorkerFactory but the map inside of it is empty on Fastlane builds, which is why it falls back to reflection. When generating an APK in Android Studio with the same gradle task as the Fastlane pipeline does, the map inside HiltWorkerFactory is not empty. All the workers are in there. Is this what you meant by providers?

Comment: Could you please update the question and focus on everything that is related here. Also maybe add the scripts you use for Fastlane and all Gradle commands. I don't think the `WorkManager` initialisation is important here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing my own WorkerFactory and injecting the necessary parameters there...

```kotlin
class BleWorkerFactory @Inject constructor(
    private val bleServiceModule: BleServiceModule,
) : WorkerFactory() {
    override fun createWorker(appContext: Context, workerClassName: String, workerParameters: WorkerParameters): ListenableWorker? {
        return when (workerClassName) {
            RemoteConfigSyncWorker::class.java.name -> RemoteConfigSyncWorker(appContext, workerParameters)
            HardwareReportWorker::class.java.name -> HardwareReportWorker(appContext, workerParameters, bleServiceModule)
            ActivitySyncWorker::class.java.name -> ActivitySyncWorker(appContext, workerParameters, bleServiceModule)
            else -> null
        }
    }
}
```

```kotlin
@Singleton
class MyDelegatingWorkerFactory @Inject constructor(
    bleWorkerFactory: BleWorkerFactory
) : DelegatingWorkerFactory() {
    init {
        addFactory(bleWorkerFactory)
    }
}
```

In my application I do not implement Configuration.Provider since I got a `RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application` when overriding the workManagerConfiguration val. Instead I set the configuration in onCreate().

```kotlin
@HiltAndroidApp
open class RandomHiltApplication : MyApplication() {

    @EntryPoint
    @InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
    interface WorkerFactoryEntryPoint {
        fun workerFactory(): MyDelegatingWorkerFactory
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        val workManagerConfiguration: Configuration = Configuration.Builder()
            .setWorkerFactory(EntryPoints.get(this, WorkerFactoryEntryPoint::class.java).workerFactory())
            .setMinimumLoggingLevel(Log.VERBOSE)
            .build()
        WorkManager.initialize(this, workManagerConfiguration)
        super.onCreate()
    }
}
```

My Fastlane builds are now working and I am happy with it. Sadly, I couldn't find out, why the HiltWorkerFactory is not working.